# Getting Taxonomy inside WP_Query Loop

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have written my custom `WP_Query` and using loop to display post content. I use `get_the_category()` to display categories of current post and it works fine. Now for some post types there are custom taxonomies instead of categories.

**Code to get categories**:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
   if(!empty($categories)){
      foreach($categories as $index => $cat){
         echo $cat->name;
      }
   }
```

Now I need to pull all taxonomies and print them in comma separated format.

I tried this:

```
$taxonomies = get_the_taxonomies();
if(!empty($taxonomies)){
   foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
         echo $taxonomy;
   }
}
```

It works and shows in this format "Taxonomy Label: Term (hyperlinked)". If the terms are more than one than it adds "and" between terms. I need only terms and if they are multiple then they should be separated by comma.

I **want to know**:

1. The best approach to achieve those results
2. Is it recommended to to use above method?
3. Can I use `regex` to extract value?
4. How can I get rid off hyperlink?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to print taxonomies or terms? `get_the_taxonomies` will get you taxonomies (like: category, post_tag, post_format) and not terms from that taxonomies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem with your code, I guess, is that you use [`get_the_taxonomies`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_taxonomies) function, which will:

> Retrieve all taxonomies of a post with just the names.

So its result will be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => category
    [1] => post_tag
    [2] => post_format
)
```

And I'm pretty sure that you want to get terms assigned to given post from all taxonomies, and not the taxonomies names...

So most probably you want to do something like this:

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), array_keys( get_the_taxonomies() ) );
foreach ( $terms as $i => $term ) {
    echo ($i ? ', ' : '') . $term->name;
}
```

And quick answers to your questions:

1. One of possible solutions above - it's hard to say if it's the best one.
2. No, your method is not a solution, I guess.
3. There is no need to use regex. You should avoid using regex when there is no need for that.
4. You can get rid of hyperlinks by getting term objects and printing them by yourself (as shown above).

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, the code does not work. It throws an error "Trying to get property of non-object" for echo line. And when I try to print `$terms` object, it returns error "invalid taxonomy". What's could be wrong?

Comment: @Alena updated my answer, one function call was missing...

Comment: Absolutely awesome, it worked now. Can you explain a bit about ternary statement, which is being used in `echo` statement?

Comment: @Alena yes. This statement checks if $i is greater than 0 and returns “, “ in such case or empty string otherwise. So it will add comma before every item except the first one.

Comment: @Alena no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these:

```
$taxonomies = get_post_taxonomies( );
print_r( $taxonomies );
echo implode( $taxonomies, ', ' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. How is it suppose to remove hyperlink?

Comment: It doesn't need to... Instead of using get_the_taxonomies, I used get_post_taxonomies.